# Best data structure for multiple choice quiz in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, data-structures, multidimensional-array

I have this dataset at the moment that I am using for a quiz application (how bad is it?):

```
   var questions =
        [
        'Question 1 text', 
        'Question 2 text'
        ]

    var answers =
        // Question 0
        [
            ['Choice 0', // Right answer
            'Choice 1',
            'Choice 2']
        ]
        // Question 1
        [
            ['Choice 0',
            'Choice 1', // Right answer
            'Choice 2']
        ]

    var correctChoice = 
        [
        '0', // Question 0, choice 0
        '1' //  Question 1, choice 1
        ]
```

So I am relying on the "invisible index" to link them all together, which is kinda hard to maintain.
Is there a better way to go about this? Are objects better? Recommendations, or best practices in general?

I have been thinking about JSON - would that be a good alternative?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Something like this should do:

```
var quiz = [
  {question: 'Question 1 text', answers: ['answer 1', 'answer 2'], correct: 0},
  {question: 'Question 2 text', answers: ['answer 1', 'answer 2'], correct: 1}
];
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var quiz = {
    questions: [
        'Question 1 text', 
        'Question 2 text'
    ],
    answers: [
        [//Question 0
            'Choice 0', // Right answer
            'Choice 1',
            'Choice 2'
        ],
        [//Question 1
            'Choice 0',
            'Choice 1', // Right answer
            'Choice 2'
        ]
    ],
    correctChoice: [
        '0', // Question 0, choice 0
        '1' //  Question 1, choice 1
    ]
}
```

Comment: Not really; that's pretty much the same.